# sql - select first value equal to 1 and duplicate value is 0

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get the first value equal to 1 and the duplicate value as 0

```
select
Client_ID,
(case
    when 1= row_number() over (partition by Client_id order by client_id)
    then 1
    else 0
end) as FLAG
FROM    Table
```

basic concept:

```
client id   flag
123           1 
123           0
178           1
178           0
178           0
178           0
178           0
389           1
233           1
```

but it keeps showing error "no more spool space"
Is there any other way to do this? Thank you,

Comment: Please could you explain what you are looking to check in the FLAG column? It would help to understand what the overall goal is for this script so that we can help as best as possible.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: in the flag column, having the first client_id label as 1, and other duplicate value label as 0, thanks

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "first" occurrence unless a column specifies the ordering.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If looks like your query is performing inefficiently. You may need to put index on ClientId.

But first of all I suggest you to update the table statistics and try again.

Comment: I pulled the data from db, so the only thing I could do is using char() or other to change data type

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but I think you are in wrong direction. there is nothing about data type

Comment: sorry, I prob misunderstood. I tried the query on other variables/columns, it generated the results. But it couldn't perform on this column

Comment: as I say, put index on ClientId and try again. It will perform better

Answer (score -1):

```
    


-- Data preparation for testing
Select 123 as client_id into #table  Union All 
Select 123 Union All
Select 178 Union All
Select 178 Union All
Select 178 Union All
Select 178 Union All
Select 178 Union All
Select 389 Union All
Select 233

-- the required query
select client_id, 
    Case When row_number() over (partition by Client_id order by client_id) = 1 
    then 1 else 0 End as Flag 
from #table
```

Comment: what is so different then OP's answer? What is the benefit of this query?

Comment: Derviş , 
It is not different, it is exactly what is posted as the outcome.

Benefit of this query is: That answers the OP's question.

Can you please run the query and compare?

Answer (score -1):

`PK` is your table `PK`, or similar combination fields that make row unique
this has been done in SqlServer 2017.

```sql
,CASE WHEN table.PK =
            FIRST_VALUE(table.PK) OVER (PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY table.PK ASC )
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as flag
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You can use backticks or four spaces to mark the SQL as code - which makes it more readable. See the formating help for details.